# Python Selenium + PhantomJS Erro: (IndexError: list index out of range)

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

My code is working and stop with error, my code:

```
import datetime
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver


def checkInternetConnection(url='http://www.google.com/', timeout=5):
    try:
        req = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
        return True
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        print 'Sem conexao com a internet aguarde...'
    return False

def main():
    while checkInternetConnection() == True:
        count = 0
        i = 0
        url = 'www.guiadosquadrinhos.com'
        #driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/home/suedx1000/Dropbox/python/scraping/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs', port=65000)
        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='C:\Python27\Tools\phantomjs\phantomjs.exe', port=65000)
        driver.get("http://www.guiadosquadrinhos.com/todas-capas-disponiveis")


        while True:
            pg = driver.page_source
            s = BeautifulSoup(pg, "html.parser")                
            pg_next = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("next_last")[2]
            pg_next.click()
            count+=1
            for link in s.find_all('a', {'class': 'suppress'}):
                print url+'/'+ link.get('href')
                print link.get('title')
        else:
            pass

        print datetime.datetime.now()
        print "Passamos em "+count+" paginas."
    else:
            print "Esta sem internet ou sua conexao caiu, reiniciando..."
main()
time.sleep(0.30)
```

> This error: File "webscraping_guiadosquadrinhos.py", line 42, in
>     main() File "webscraping_guiadosquadrinhos.py", line 29, in
>   main pg_next = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("next_last")[2]
>   IndexError: lis index out of range

Comment: Please show the necessary page markup to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Check if the `while True` loop fails on the first iteration. If not, consider adding a delay after `pg_next.click()'.

Comment: The error is simple to understand - your code is referencing the 3rd element with class name 'next_last', and there are not 3 matching elements.

Comment: Infact there are more than 4 element that satisfy the xpath expression(//*[@class ='next_last']).But driver.get did not load anything and hence exception was thrown. I just added some wait that solved the problem..hehe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me below worked- I just tuned your code. I supposed you want to go back and back.

My Edits:Using wait-important,defined encoding and frame size.

```
import datetime,os,sys
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def checkInternetConnection(url='http://www.google.com/', timeout=5):
    try:
        req = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
        return True
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        print 'Sem conexao com a internet aguarde...'
        return False
def main():
    while checkInternetConnection() == True:
        count = 0
        i = 0
        url = 'www.guiadosquadrinhos.com'
        #driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/home/suedx1000/Dropbox/python/scraping/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs', port=65000)
        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r"C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/plumb/phantomjs.exe", port=65000)
        driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
        driver.get("http://www.guiadosquadrinhos.com/todas-capas-disponiveis")
        driver.implicitly_wait(50)
        while True:          
            pg = driver.page_source
            s = BeautifulSoup(pg, "html.parser")
            for link in s.find_all('a', {'class': 'suppress'}):
                print url+'/'+ link.get('href').encode('utf-8')
                print link.get('title').encode('utf-8')            
            count+=1
            print count
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='next_last']")))
            wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='Lista_album_capas']")))
            pg_next = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='next_last']")         
            pg_next[0].click()            
        else:
            pass
        time.sleep(1)

        print datetime.datetime.now()
        print "Passamos em "+count+" paginas."
    else:
            print "Esta sem internet ou sua conexao caiu, reiniciando..."
main()
```

Comment: You should explain what you changed and why.

Comment: @JeffC- I edited the answer, though edits were described in the comment of OP's question a bit.

Comment: Not working, your wait this code execution?
Here stop code count 329, page have 527.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Dropbox/python/scraping/webscraping_guiadosquadrinhos.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "Dropbox/python/scraping/webscraping_guiadosquadrinhos.py", line 29, in main
    pg_next = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("next_last")[2]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: What u mean by 527? there are about 5K to be extracted!!.I tested this script and successfully extracted upto 638 with no problem at all, then i stopped. extracted text link https://www.dropbox.com/s/tvmx2min65equlv/extracted.txt?dl=0